# Which one is a parent of child class ChildWidget (PySide)?

Tags: python, class, parent

Can you help me and explain why `print(str(self.parent()))` returns MainWindow and `self.print_base()` returns QWidget? Where is parent() method defined? In `super(ChildWidget, self).__init__(parent)` parent goes to MainWindow init or in QWidget init?

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.do_something() #sanity check
        self.cw = ChildWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.cw)
        self.show()

    def do_something(self):

        print 'doing something!'

class ChildWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def print_base(self):
        for base in self.__class__.__bases__:
            print base.__name__

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(ChildWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        print(str(self.parent()))
        self.print_base()

        self.button1 = QtGui.QPushButton()
        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.do_something_else)

        self.button2 = QtGui.QPushButton()
        self.button2.clicked.connect(self.parent().do_something)

        self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button2)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.show()

    def do_something_else(self):
        print 'doing something else!'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dealing with two types of hierarchy: 1) widgets hierary; 2) python classes hiearchy.  The method "print_base" is listing all the base classes in a python POV, while "parent" returns the widget instance where the child widget is attached to.

Comment: I need more theory reading. I'm learning by doing and by myself. So, base class and parent class are not the same thing. Can you tell me is `parent()` QWidget's method?

Comment: Yes, parent method is implemented in QtWidget's class.